# I defined a controller method for google_oauth2 for devise, but it's still missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I try to authenticate, I get the message:

```
"Not found. Authentication passthru."
```

I added an action_missing method to get a clue: when it's called, it logs:

```
  Parameters: {"provider"=>"google_oauth2"}
```

So it would appear that I'm getting a complaint that I'm missing the very method that I've defined. Why is my action missing when it's defined?

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def action_missing(provider)
    logger.debug provider
  end

end
```

devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
  'my',
  'secret',
  {
      :name => "google",
      :scope => 'email, profile',
      :prompt => 'select_account',
      :image_aspect_ratio => 'square',
      :image_size => 50
  }
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]
  def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

    # Uncomment the section below if you want users to be created if they don't exist
    # unless user
    #     user = User.create(name: data["name"],
    #        email: data["email"],
    #        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    #     )
    # end
    user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, someone else may find it edifying:

in devise.rb, I had:

```
 {
      :name => 'google', <====== BAD IDEA!
      :scope => 'email, profile',
      :prompt => 'select_account',
      :image_aspect_ratio => 'square',
      :image_size => 50
  }
```

the first item, the `:name`, was copied from another omniauth tutorial. It seems to be a very bad idea. Removing it made things go.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide :name to your config settings you have to call it from the given name. Also your Authorized redirect URIs will have the name "google" as you specify here.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in and answering! Can you provide a code snippet to go along with your answer? It might be easier to understand that way.